# Add Marker to Google maps inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have trouble making a function that will add Marker to my google map after it is instantiated. Here is my whole jQuery plugin :

```
function ($) {

$.fn.eqpMap = function (options) {
    var mapContainer = this;

    $.fn.map.container = this;

    $.fn.map.map = null;

    $.fn.map.defaults = {
        adr1: null,
        adr2: null,
        adr3: null,
        cp: null,
        ville: null,
        geocodeAPI: "gouv",
        coordinates: {
            lat: null,
            lon: null
        },
        pays: "France",
        zoom: 15,
        osm: {
            layer: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            options: {
                fullscreenControl: true
            }
        },
        google: {
            options: {
                googleKey: null,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false
            }
        }
    };


    var opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.map.defaults, options);

    function displayMap(location) { //location {lat: 1, lon: 1}

        if (opts.geocodeAPI == "google") {
            opts.google.options.center = location;
            $.fn.map.map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer[0], opts.google.options);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: opts.google.options.center, map: $.fn.map.map });
        } else {
            //Récupère l'attribut id de l'element
            let idContainer = $(mapContainer).attr('id');
            opts.osm.options.center = location;
            if (typeof L.Control.Fullscreen == 'undefined') {
                delete opts.osm.options.fullscreenControl;
            }
            $.fn.map.map = L.map(idContainer, opts.osm.options);
            L.tileLayer(opts.osm.layer, {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo($.fn.map.map);
            $.fn.map.map.attributionControl.setPrefix(false);
            var marker = new L.marker(opts.osm.options.center, {});
            $.fn.map.map.addLayer(marker);
        }
    }

    return this;
};

$.fn.eqpMap.addMarker = function (marker) {
    var markers = null;
    if ($.fn.map.opts.geocodeAPI !== "google") {
        markers = new L.marker(marker, {});
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log('osm');
            $.fn.map.map.addLayer(markers);
        })
    } else {
        markers = {lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lon};
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log('google');            
            console.log(markers);
            var markerGoogle = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markers, map: $.fn.map.map });
            markerGoogle.setMap($.fn.map.map);
        })
    }
}

 }(jQuery));
```

Everytime I try to add a marker in my `addMarker` method it just won't because it can't find `$.fn.map.map`. I also tried to access the map via `window.google.maps.map` but it seems to not work, none of these throw me any errors to help me with.

Comment: How do you attach the map to the DOM?

Comment: @gmazoni i do not quite understand but, map is created using google objects (i maybe wrong) here :
$.fn.map.map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer[0], opts.google.options);

Comment: I am trying to undestand the context with your $.fn.map.map, maybe its because addMarker are trying to add to a map that are not initialized

Comment: @gmazoni that's why i have an eventListener in my addMarker method because i wan't to wait for the page to be loaded and the map initialized.

Comment: Do you garantee that "on load" waits for the map initialization? Can you use the callback [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)?

Comment: @gmazoni i don't know how but it working by now ..